# How to do Multiple ThenInclude navigation props after One Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

For a TestType I wanted to include both navigation props Schoolclass and Subject.

I could do a:

```
.Include(t => t.TestType)
 .ThenInclude(x => x.Subject)
```

but not a:

```
.Include(t => t.TestType)
.ThenInclude(x => x.Subject)
.ThenInclude(x => x.Schoolclass)
```

Thus I tried a little trick and that worked:

I included the TestType 2 times...

```
var test = await context.Tests.Where(t => t.SchoolyearId == schoolyearId)
                                          .Include(t => t.TestType)
                                          .ThenInclude(x => x.Subject)
                                           .Include(t => t.TestType)
                                          .ThenInclude(x => x.Schoolclass)
                                           .AsNoTracking()
                                          .ToListAsync();
```

Is that the official approach or is there a better one?

**UPDATE**

```
   public class TestType
    {
        public TestType()
        {
            Tests = new HashSet<Test>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public ISet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
        public Schoolyear Schoolyear { get; set; }  
        public Schoolclass Schoolclass { get; set; }   
        public Subject Subject { get; set; }
        public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is your object definition ?

Comment: object definition? What exactly do you mean? Which object? :-)

Comment: The definition for your objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EFCore Linq ThenInclude Two Foreign Keys To Same Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506692/efcore-linq-theninclude-two-foreign-keys-to-same-table). I.e. yes, it's official.

Answer (score 8):

the best way is that you write before, With two .Include(t => t.TestType)

```
var test = await context.Tests.Where(t => t.SchoolyearId == schoolyearId)
                                      .Include(t => t.TestType)
                                      .ThenInclude(x => x.Subject)
                                       .Include(t => t.TestType)
                                      .ThenInclude(x => x.Schoolclass)
                                       .AsNoTracking()
                                      .ToListAsync();
```

If you see the query result in SQL Profiler, the query is that you pretend, without repeating the include to TestType (only 1 join with that table)

You have another way to do it, but i prefer the before way!

```
.Include("TestType.Subject") 
.Include("TestType.Schoolclass")
```

Answer (score 3):

If such type of includes is common in your codebase it may be useful to create a couple of extension methods like this:

```
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeMany<TEntity, TProperty>(
            [NotNull] this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
            [NotNull] Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath,
            [NotNull] params Expression<Func<TProperty, object>>[] nextProperties
            )
            where TEntity : class
        {
            foreach (var nextProperty in nextProperties)
            {
                source = source.Include(navigationPropertyPath)
                    .ThenInclude(nextProperty);
            }

            return source;
        }

        public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeMany<TEntity, TProperty>(
            [NotNull] this IQueryable<TEntity>source,
            [NotNull] Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> navigationPropertyPath,
            [NotNull] params Expression<Func<TProperty, object>>[] nextProperties)
            where TEntity : class
        {
            foreach (var nextProperty in nextProperties)
            {
                source = source.Include(navigationPropertyPath)
                    .ThenInclude(nextProperty);
            }

            return source;
        }
```

With this, you'll be able to change your query to

```
var test = await context.Tests
    .Where(t => t.SchoolyearId == schoolyearId)
    .IncludeMany(t => t.TestType,
       x => x.Subject,
       x => x.Schoolclass
    )
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Although this does not support going more than 2 levels in depth.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is the only one that exists in 1.1.0 :)

Better one is little different - do not load all objects in one query (DB will join 4 tables - `Tests`, `TestType`, `Schoolyear`, `Schoolclass`), because this may cause unnecessary data growth (when you will have *a lot* or records in `tests`).

If some of your tables (Schoolyear? or even TestType?) contains relatively small amount of records (comparing to "main" `Tests` table) - you can load `TestTypes.Include(x => x.Subject).Include(x => x.Schoolclass)` first, save them in some list, and then query only `Tests` without extra "Include". But as soon as you already have `TestType` with all required dependencies in memory - they may be accessed from memory.

Moreover, if some of your tables are changing rarely - use [Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory) to read them from DB once and re-read when necessary (remove appropriate cache entry in controllers that manage this tables).

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't use `Include` twice?

```
  var myVar= ((MyContext) _context)
            .MasterEntity
            .Include(x => x.FirstChild)
            .Include(x=>x.FirstChild.FirstGrandChild)
            .Include(x=>x.FirstChild.SecondGrandChild)
            .Where(x => x.Id== input)
            .ToList();
```