# How to filter nested entities of the same type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

The following is a simplified version of my actual situation. let's say I have this `Person` entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // etc.

    // Some navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

And I wrote an extension method to filter based on one or more properties:

```
public static IQueryable<Person> Filter(this IQueryable<Person> query,
                                        string name = null, int? thingId = null, 
                                        Foo etc = null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        query = query.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));

    if (thingId.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(p => p.Things.Count > 0 && 
                                 p.Things.Any(t => t.Id == thingId.Value));
    // etc.

    return query;
}
```

..which I can use like this:

```
var query = context.People.Filter(name, thingId);
var filteredPeople = query.Include(p => p.Things).Include(__).OrderBy(__).ToList();
```

I wanted to make `Person` a nested entity (i.e., each person has a collection of persons). So, I added the following properties:

```
public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Parent")]
public int? ParentId { get; set; }
public virtual Person Parent { get; set; }
```

And now I'm struggling to implement the filtering logic. What I need is:

- A parent `Person` is to be included if it matches the filters *or* if one of its descendants does.
- A child `Person` is included only if it meets the above criteria.

For the second problem, I will probably try the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801205/13485806) but I need to solve the first problem first. I tried to create a recursive expression like below:

```
private static IQueryable<Person> FilterByName(this IQueryable<Person> query, string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) return query;

    Expression<Func<Person, bool>> selector = (p) => 
        p.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()) 
        || p.Children.AsQueryable().FilterByName(name).Any();

    return query.Where(selector);
}
```

..but I get an exception saying that it *"cannot be translated into a store expression"*.

The only other solution I could think of is to recursively iterate the children's tree and try to construct the list manually, which is inefficient because it will require too many queries.

**How can I efficiently filter the collection of `Person` and their descendants?**

Comment: Don't try to do that with EF. It is a recursive CTE query which is not supported by any current EF versions. So better to run SQL via Dapper.

Comment: altho Svyatoslav comment is probably not what you want  to hear its kind of correct. or at least i dont know away of doing that... instead I do the  `recursively iterate the children's tree` in code.... so you need ur db to understand parent child and the links... the way i do this is add a parentId to the Person table, then in code you can build a tree model.... and then apply your logic but you will not be able to generate a query to build this for you straight from EF.... or anything really, you would need to more to a non relational db... if thats the case even then im not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987365/implementing-recursive-property-loading-in-ef-core saying that.....

Comment: @Seabizkit Thank you. I probably will have to load it in code for now. I just wanted the question to get more attention in case there's a way that I couldn't think of, hence, the bounty.

Comment: I'd start with replacing p.Children.AsQueryable().FilterByName(name) with contents of FilterByName to see which query will be produced by EF, if any (so do filtering without separate method, in place).

Comment: @Evk How do you suggest I do that? `FilterByName` merely contains the `selector` expression as shown above. If I try to replace `.AsQueryable().FilterByName...` with `.Any(selector)`, for example, the compiler complains that `selector` is not (yet) initialized.

Comment: Ah I missed it's recursive (in a sense)... Then I agree with first commenter - you'll need to use raw sql to make that efficient.

Comment: HierachryID would be a ms sql server specific way to approach your problem. https://softwarehut.com/blog/tech/hierarchyid-entity-framework . Pretty sure you could adapt that concept to work for most databases.

Comment: @fuchs777 I will look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to create a query that achieves the following:

1. A parent Person is to be included if it matches the filters or if one of its descendants does.
2. A child Person is included only if it meets the above criteria.

If we invert our way of thinking, and realize the fact there are no parent or children entities, only people, we can rewrite our criteria to say the following:

1. If an person matches the filters, we want to include that person and all of it's ancestors.

This greatly simplifies the query we need to execute and gives identical results.

Now, as some comments have indicated, Entity Framework doesn't have a lot built in as far as hieratical queries are concerned. This doesn't mean that we can't use EF, but we do need to write and execute a raw SQL query.

EF will still take care of the object mapping, and change tracking if you want to save entities to the database.

This doesn't have the ability to be further extended by Linq such as `.Where()` or `.Include()` as it is a non-compostable query.

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> FilterPeople(this DbSet<Person> people, string name)
{
    return people.FromSqlRaw(
        "WITH child AS (" +
        "    SELECT * FROM People" +
        "    WHERE Name LIKE {0}" +
        "    UNION ALL" +
        "    SELECT parent.* FROM People parent" +
        "    INNER JOIN child ON parent.Id = child.ParentId" +
        ") SELECT * FROM child",
        $"%{name}%")
        .AsEnumerable();
}
```

This translates into the parameterized query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'WITH child AS (SELECT * FROM People WHERE Name LIKE @p0 UNION ALL SELECT parent.* FROM People parent INNER JOIN child ON parent.Id = child.ParentId) SELECT * FROM child',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',
@p0=N'%Dick%'
```

Comment: This looks promising; I'm going to give it a try. Two points though: 1) I think I will have to use `.SqlQuery()` instead of `.FromSqlRaw()` since I'm using EF6. 2) Do you know if this type of query is possible in MS-Access? (because that's what I'm currently using; I didn't mention it in the question because I didn't think it would be relevant)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Access but a quick search yielded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763016/is-it-possible-to-create-a-recursive-query-in-access. The answers in that question are 10 years old so I don't know if anything has changed, however they suggest doing an arbitrary number of left joins in the query instead. This works if you know the maximum depth of your hierarchy or if you are satisfied at a certain depth. For example using 3 left joins would yield the child, parent, grand parent and great grand parent.

Comment: Perhaps you should tag this question with `access` in an attempt to draw attention from someone that knows access better. And if it does I hope my answer serves as a stepping stone towards the final one!

Comment: No need for that because a) I'll be kind of changing the question in a way that invalidates the current answer and b) there doesn't seem to be much hope for this to work in Access with pure SQL. I really appreciate your help. This will be useful for future projects and I actually have plans to migrate this project to either MySQL or MSSQL soon anyway. I actually tested this with SQL Server and it works very well although it includes children that don't match the filters (2nd requirement) but I'll probably be able to figure out a way to handle this. Thanks again for your help!