# EFCore Linq ThenInclude Two Foreign Keys To Same Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?
`ProjectActivityTasks` has the `UnitOfMeasureId` and the `ProjectActivityTaskTypeId`. With the way it is written, it thinks that `UnitOfMeasure` goes to `ProjectActivityTaskType`. It is erroring out on the `ThenInclude` for `UnitOfMeasure` saying

> ProjectActivityTaskType does not contain a definition for UnitOfMeasure

which is correct. `UnitOfMeasure` goes to `ProjectActivityTasks`.

I was referencing this page but it does not seem to work this way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

```
var qry = await _projectActivityRepository.GetAll()
.Include(x => x.ProjectActivityVehicles)
  .ThenInclude(x => x.Vehicle)
.Include(x => x.ProjectActivityTasks)
  .ThenInclude(x => x.ProjectActivityTaskType)
  .ThenInclude(x => x.UnitOfMeasure)
.Where(x => x.Id == Id && x.TenantId == (int)AbpSession.TenantId)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can (and should) repeat the `Include(x => x.ProjectActivityTasks)` part:

```
var qry = await _projectActivityRepository.GetAll()
.Include(x => x.ProjectActivityVehicles)
  .ThenInclude(x => x.Vehicle)
.Include(x => x.ProjectActivityTasks)
  .ThenInclude(x => x.ProjectActivityTaskType)
.Include(x => x.ProjectActivityTasks)
  .ThenInclude(x => x.UnitOfMeasure)
.Where(x => x.Id == Id && x.TenantId == (int)AbpSession.TenantId)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```