# Entity Framework Include Nest collection and nested properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 4 classes

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders{ get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
    public OrderType Type { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public string StockItem { get; set; }
}

public class OrderType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Using entity frameworks i want to pull out all the information starting at Customer level. I can get most information out but i am stuck getting OrderType to show against the order.

This is what i have so far.

```
var customerOrderDetails = _myOrderRepository
                           .GetAll()
                           .Include(o => o.Orders)
                           .ThenInclude(l => l.OrderLines)
```

I've tried added select after the o.Orders but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See the last example in the **Including multiple levels** section of the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) documentation.

Comment: *doesn't seem to work* Please elaborate. Error? No results? ... I suspect you're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46506877/861716).

Comment: If i add it like this .Include(o => o.Orders.Select(t => t.Type)), i get IEnumerable<OrderType> does not contain a definition for OrderLines

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var customerOrderDetails = _myOrderRepository
                           .GetAll()
                           .Include(o => o.Orders)
                           .Include(o => o.Orders.Select(l => l.OrderLines))
                           .Include(o => o.Orders.Select(t => t.Type))
```

Comment: You didn't read OP's last comment. Neither did the upvoter, so now you're probably not inclined to deleting this answer any more.

Comment: What are you trying to say? Is there anything wrong that I did?

Comment: I'm getting the following error : System.InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'o => {from Order l in o.Orders select [l].OrderLines}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

Comment: *Is there anything wrong that I did?* (1) Your answer applies to EF6, but not to EF Core which is the target of the question (2) Even if it was EF6 question, then it would have been for sure duplicate and should have been closed rather than answered.

Comment: @Saadi The only right thing to do here is to delete your answer. It's wrong, it doesn't help OP, it doesn't help anyone finding this question later. Don't stick to these futile rep points you inexplicably received from two upvoters.

Comment: But there is nothing mention in question about entity framework version.

Comment: @Saadi Well, the ef-core tag was added because it was obvious from the question's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
var customerOrderDetails = _myOrderRepository
                       .GetAll()
                       .Include(o => o.Orders)
                       .ThenInclude(l => l.OrderLines)
                       .Include(o => o.Orders).ThenInclude(t => t.Type)
```

Adding another Include after the OrderLines and then selecting the type seemed to work.